# Hide default buttons in DialogPreference

Tags: android, button, dialog

I currently have a custom Dialog class that extends DialogPreference(which of course is a part of a PreferenceScreen).

This Dialog have custom buttons which handles save and cancel. Therefor i would like to get rid of the standard "positive" and "negative" buttons.

Tried using AlertDialog getButton method but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your xml use the following instead of DialogPreference:

```
<Preference
    android:title="This acts as a button"
    android:key="button"
    android:summary="This can act like a button to create it's own dialog"/>
```

Then in the java:

```
Preference button = (Preference)findPreference("button");
button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                showDialog(MY_DIALOG); // let's say MY_DIALOG is 'final int MY_DIALOG = 1;' in the class body
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Then add to your class body:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {       

    case SHOW_APP_STRING:
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View mylayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);


     final AlertDialog myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
     .setView(mylayout)
     .show();
      //The buttons are below the dialog so you can close the dialog within your button listeners
      Button save = (Button)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.save);
      Button cancel = (Button)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
      //set onClickListeners for both of your buttons

      return myDialog;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best method, but it's how I do it, and it works.

Comment: Thanks alot for pushing me into the right direction. With your help i could achieve what i wanted.

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily complex. Simply set the text of both buttons to null and they'll disappear. setPositiveButtonText(null);
        setNegativeButtonText(null);
In the constructor.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to create a custom `DialogPreference` you have to create your own class and extend `DialogPreference`. To hide the buttons use  `setPositiveButtonText(null);` and `setNegativeButtonText(null);` in the Constructor

```
package ...;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class MyDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public MyDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPositiveButtonText(null);
        setNegativeButtonText(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `null` instead of empty string.

Comment: It is also possible to place them into onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) instead of constructor.

Comment: @LEGALLBenoît this solution works perfectly. Should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `defStyleAttr` to `R.attr.preferenceScreenStyle` in your class extending `DialogPreference` constructor.

It removes the dialog's button bar